# Buying a bike: Older, used high-quality components or new average-quality components?

Tags: road-bike, product-rec

I realize that fit and personal comfort, etc. are most important, but, I need some advice.
I just got into duathlons and triathlons this year, and started with a very low end bike. I'm now looking to upgrade, but not trying to go crazy.

My question is regarding good versus average components. Are older great components better than new average components?
For an average rider, with some racing goals, etc, does new outweigh better, or does quality always outweigh age?

None of the items are bad, just older or better.

I'm specifically comparing a used 2007 bike with a Shimano 105 groupset and a 2016 bike with a Tiagra groupset.

Comment: Generally speaking, an older bike will be "good enough" and the price reflects that, adjusted for wear.   Used  carbon bikes should be given a good clean and a close inspection first.    A used bike that fits you will get you there better and faster than a new bike that doesn't fit.    We don't do specific shopping recommendations though because they're of limited use in the long term.   A new bike would be "best" but we can't all just do that.  My race bike is a 1998 alloy frame, its good enough.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Dianna. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site. In it's current form this question doesn't have long term value to others, but you can [edit](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/posts/42858/edit) it to be better. See, for example a related question: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5209/looking-for-a-first-race-worthy-road-bike-what-should-i-look-for?rq=1. If you recast the question to specify the frames and groupsets, and ask how the 2008 versions compare to the 2016 versions then question can have more lasting value.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Criggie, so that's kind of my point. They are all at similar prices, but I know the Cannondale components (Shimano 105 for example) are better than the Fuji components (Shimano tiagra). But the Fuji is brand new. Are the components that much better on the Cannondale, or does the brand new part outweigh it, since they are still decent components?  Does that make sense?

Comment: Consider, if you're riding in the TT position (and your race routes aren't mountainous) - you would be better off with a TT specific bike. Position is everything - and although you can put clip-ons onto standard bars - the geometry of a TT bike is somewhat different. Secondhand TT bikes with reasonable spec don't look all that expensive - I guess a lot of the expense is in road STI shifters - which TT bikes don't have (bar end shifters).

Comment: Cannonballs and Fujimount and Fred's handmake bikes will generally use components from 2.5 main suppliers.  That's Shimano, Sram, and the higher end also has Campagnolo.   The quality of a Shimano 105 is the same across different bikes for the same year, plus wear.  HOWEVER a 2016 105 component will have some "trickledown" from higher models, and may very well be the equivalent of an ultegra class from 2010 or a dura-ace class from 2005.  Really depends how much of your disposable income you can afford to put against this hobby.

Comment: I know you are asking about components, but you are buying an entire bike. A Cannondale frame is more expensive than Fuji for several reasons, and that is reflected in the price. To make any guesses about which one is a better deal, we'd need to know which bikes these are.

Comment: Plenty of bad-ass bikes built in the 70s, 80s ... some bike companies are out of business (E-Moto) and some designs are no longer made (Townie only makes 7 speeds now, they used to build 24, 21 and my personal fav, the 2100d that has 2 up front & 8 in the back for a total of 16 speeds!). For your purposes a gently used ride will cost significantly less.

Comment: If you're buying an older bike with a better quality groupset make sure it's not worn out too. The derailleurs shouldn't be the problem but check the chain stretch and if it's excessive it's probably worn the cassette out too. Look for the the teeth on the chainring and cassette resembling sharks fins or hooks. It might negate any saving from buying one over the other.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to remain general - and assuming both bikes are a good fit for you, I'd base the decision on Warranty.

The older bike is a decade out of date and will have a decade of use on it... but that could be anything from 0 km up to 50,000 km of travel.  So it should be in the "couple of hundred dollars" range at most.

The new bike will have a store warranty.  If you feel you will need that support, then a new bike is a reasonable idea.  But the new bike will cost you five to ten times as much as the used bike.

Answer (score -4):

2007 components are pretty old. I really like the newer ones. So many great bikes now. In your price range I'd go Cannondale CAAD12 or Trek ALR aluminum frames. Should be able to find one cheap right now before new models come out.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @RGRHON. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site. It's not a chat site. Also check out [answer].